# I would like to implement promises my own, but I could not find the solution

Tags: ios, swift, promisekit

Here I would like to implement 'Promise' like blocks. But I'm not able to set the result for the blocks.

Here I have 2 Challenges :

1. I'm trying to implement simple Promise example for getting a full
   string from the first name and last name.
2. I would like to call '*then*' multiple times.

   - First I want to get the full name from both.
   - Then convert into Uppercase.
   - Then convert into lowercase.
     ..so on (mean to say multiple '*then*' conditions with some task.)

How can I achieve multiple times?

Here is my example.

```
class Promise<T> {

    private var resultHandler : ((_ result:T)->())?
    private var errorHandler :  ((_ error:String)->())?
    private var final : (()->())?

    func resolve(_ value: T) {
        resultHandler?(value)
        final?()
    }

    func reject(_ value: String) {
        errorHandler?(value)
        final?()
    }

    func then(_ block:@escaping (_ result:T)->()) {
        resultHandler = block
    }

    func error(_ block:@escaping (_ result:String)->()) {
        errorHandler = block
    }

    func finally(_ block:@escaping ()->()) {
        final = block
    }

}

func getFullName(firstname: String, lastname: String) -> Promise<String> {
    let p = Promise<String>()

    if firstname.count > 0 && lastname.count > 0 {
        let name = firstname + " "  + lastname
        p.resolve(name)
    }
    else {
        print("--")
            p.reject("Firstname and Lastname can't be empty" )
    }
    return p
}



let p = getFullName(firstname: "Alen", lastname: "Stel")
p.then { (name) in
    print("Name", name)
}
```

Comment: Not related, but ... don't use old syntax for closures, just declare type of closure's parameter/s: `((_ result:T)->())?` --> `((T)->Void)?`. Also don't use underscore `_` before closure parameter `then(_ block...)` --> `then(block...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to chain things like `then`, you need to chain the handlers, for example:

```
func then(block: @escaping (T)->()) {
    if let oldHandler = resultHandler {
        resultHandler = {
            oldHandler($0)
            block($0)
        }
    } else {
        resultHandler = block
    }
}
```

Or you can simplify things by making `resultHandler` non-optional:

```
private var resultHandler: (T)->() = {}
...
func then(block: @escaping (T)->()) {
    resultHandler = { [oldHandler] in
        oldHandler($0)
        block($0)
    }
}
```

You can do similar things to `error` and `finally` if you like.

To your existing code, you're attaching `then` after the Promise is resolved. You have to manage that case. You can do that with a enum `State` (like `.pending`, `.resolved`, `.error`) or just using some variables like:

```
private var value: T?
...
func then(block: @escaping (T)->()) {
    if let value = value {
        block(value)
    } else {
        resultHandler = { [oldHandler] in
            oldHandler($0)
            block($0)
        }
    }

 func resolve(_ value: T) {
    self.value = value
    resultHandler(value)
    resultHandler = {}
    final()
    final = {}
}
```

(Or something along those lines. I haven't completely tested this.)

Keep in mind that this is all thread-unsafe, so you have to be careful about adding `.then` clauses or resolving on different queues, but that can be fine in a simple Promise type as long as you keep that in mind (and makes it dramatically simpler....)